# Fetching images with c# htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to fetch images from sites like Google images and yandex (a russian search engine).
I use xpaths for the purpose. While, on yandex, i am able to fetch the image thumbnails (ie, their urls), i am not able to fetch the bigger image (which is possibly javascript generated, when one clicks on the image).
On google images, I am not able to fetch even the thumbnails. The xpath that i use for google images is:

```
@"//div[@class='rg_di']/img"
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your previous question. If it is, please do not ask questions more than once; if it is not, in general it is a good idea to explain how a new question is different to your previous similar ones.

Comment: @halfer I'll take care of that. Actually I didn't get any more replies and so thought better to explain my whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath instead: `@"//div[@class='rg_di']//img"`. You should note that the img tag is not directly under the div tag as your XPath expression states (// instead of /).

Comment: If you want a more direct approach you shloud do @"//img[@class='rg_i']" instead.